# SQL GROUP BY multiple columns with one non-repeating column

Tags: sql

I am attempting to query multiple columns in order to display the heaviest ship for each builder/company name.

[image]

When using my above query I instead receive the results for every ships weight instead of the heaviest ship for each builder. I have spent a few hours trying to discern what is needed to cause the builder column to be distinct.

Comment: Can you share the original data for the `ship` table? Or is that it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove 'shipname' from the `group by` list to get the max weight for each builder, then join the query to the original table to get the ship name as the following:

```
select T.builder, T.shipname, T.weight
from ship T join
(
  select builder, max(weight) mx
  from ship
  group by builder
) D
on T.builder=D.builder and T.weight=D.mx
order by T.builder
```

You may also use `DESNE_RANK()` function to get the required results as the following:

```
select top 1 with ties 
       builder, shipname, weight
from ship
order by dense_rank() over (partition by builder order by weight desc)
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/IPsrUwDj) on SQL Server (I supposed that you are using SQL Server from the posted image).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to apply a `GROUP BY` clause in this situation. It will be sufficient to check whether the ship's weight is the highest weight for the current builder. This can be done with a simple sub query:

```
SELECT
  builder, shipname, weight
FROM
  ship
WHERE
  weight = (SELECT MAX(i.weight) FROM ship i WHERE i.builder = ship.builder)
ORDER BY builder;
```

Answer (score 0):

I always think the simplest way to handle a complex query starts with a Common Table Expression (CTE). If you’re new to this, a CTE is a query which is run as a first step, so that you can use its results in the next step.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT builder, max(weight) AS weight
    FROM data
    GROUP BY builder
)
SELECT *
FROM cte JOIN data ON cte.builder=data.builder AND cte.weight=data.weight;
```

The CTE above fetches the rows with the maximum weights:

```sql
SELECT builder, max(weight) AS weight
FROM data
GROUP BY builder
```

| builder | weight |
| --- | --- |
| Ace Shipbuilding Corp | 95000 |
| Ajax | 90000 |
| Jones | 95000 |
| Master | 80000 |

You now have the maximum weight for each builder.

You then join this result with the original data to fetch the rows which match the weights and builders:

| builder | weight | builder | shipname | weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Master | 80000 | Master | Queen Shiney | 80000 |
| Jones | 95000 | Jones | Princess of Florida | 95000 |
| Ajax | 90000 | Ajax | Prince Al | 90000 |
| Ace Shipbuilding Corp | 95000 | Ace Shipbuilding Corp | Ocean V | 95000 |
| Ace Shipbuilding Corp | 95000 | Ace Shipbuilding Corp | Sea Peace | 95000 |

Note that there is a tie for the **Ace Shipbuilding Corp**.

The above solution supposes that the data you have in your sample is the original data.